# Getting values from localstorage and resolving Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do have some noobie question.
I need to get a value from localstorage, but I am using some specifc methods that we have in our app.
I am setting my value with:

```
public setValue = async (key: keyof StorageContent, val: any) => {
    if (!localStorage) {
      console.warn("StorageManager: localStorage is not defined");
      return;
    }
    // Let's convert `undefined` values to `null` to get the value consistent
    if (val === undefined) {
      val = null;
    } else {
      val = JSON.stringify(val);
    }

    return localStorage.setItem(key, val);
  };
```

After this is done I am using

```
 static getBackendVersion() {
    return StorageManager.getValue("backendVersion");
  }
```

`getValue`

```
public getValue = async (key: keyof StorageContent) => {
    if (!localStorage) {
      console.warn("StorageManager: localStorage is not defined");
      return undefined;
    }

    const item = localStorage ? localStorage.getItem(key) : null;
    if (!item || item === "null") {
      return undefined;
    }
    try {
      return JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (e) {
      return undefined;
    }
  };
```

In my react component where I am using state and component id mount to get this done

```
 state: Readonly<IMainScreenState> = {
    screenKey: RouteHelper.getScreenRouteKey(this.props.match),
    apiVersion: "",
  };

  public componentDidMount() {
    const backendVer = StorageHelper.getBackendVersion();
    this.setState({ apiVersion: backendVer });
  }
```

After this i want to render this

```
 <aside className="Version">
    <span>F:{AppConfig.PlatformVersion} / </span>
    <span> B:{apiVersion}</span>
 </aside>
```

But this is getting me error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
In conolse log i have

[image: console.log]

i know that i can get this with `localStorage.getItem()` but we need to use this helpers to get this done clean

Comment: You forgot to  use `await`. `const backendVer = await StorageHelper.getBackendVersion();`

Comment: tahnks you are right i was missing async, but i had to rewrite this a bit as i did not want to use async/await in `componentDidMount`